# Difference between plt.imshow and cv2.imshow?

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, image-processing, imshow

Why is there a difference in the output image when calling the same image using `plt.imshow` & `cv2.imshow()`?

Here is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

src=cv2.imread('fruits1.jpg') # Source image

plt.subplot(211),plt.imshow(src),plt.title('image')
plt.xticks([]),plt.yticks([])
plt.show()

cv2.imshow('image',src)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyWindow()
```

Here is the image from `plt.imshow`:

[image: image output for plt.imshow]

and the second one is the original image:

[image: image output from cv2.show]

Is there some modification required with the `plt.imshow()`?

Comment: OpenCV uses BGR channel ordering, but matplotlib uses RGB. So there is a channel reversal ordering between the two needed when going from one to the other.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Because OpenCV stores images in BGR order instead of RGB.

Try `plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))`

See [here](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/11/03/display-matplotlib-rgb-image/) for an example.

Answer (score 3):

OpenCV - BGR and Matplotlib - RGB

**OpenCV:**

https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/display_image/display_image.html

[image]

**Matplotlib:**

https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can either use :

```py
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
                        OR
plt.imshow(image[:,:,::-1])  # here we are reversing the channel order
```