# Apply MatplotLib to OpenCV image

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, scikit-image

There is my picture,[image]

when I  use following code in matplotlib, I can get a picture like this :

[image]

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.color import rgb2hed
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

roi_select = cv2.imread(r"C:\Users\hutao\Desktop\cell.png")
roi_select_11 = rgb2hed(roi_select)
cmap_dab = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('mycmap', ['white','saddlebrown'])
plt.imshow(roi_select_11[:,:,0],cmap=cmap_dab)
```

But when I use OpenCV ,there is my code :

```
def get_mpl_colormap(cmap_name):
    cmap =   LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('mycmap', ['white','saddlebrown'])
    sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap)
    color_range = sm.to_rgba(np.linspace(0, 1, 256), bytes=True)[:,2::-1]
    return color_range.reshape(256, 1, 3)

roi_select = cv2.imread(r"C:\Users\hutao\Desktop\cell.png")
image_bgr = cv2.applyColorMap(roi_select[:,:,0],get_mpl_colormap('bwr'))
cv2.imshow('image with colormap', image_bgr)
cv2.waitKey()
```

I can't get the same picture,there is the OpenCV's picture
[image]
How can I get the same picture in OpenCV like figure2?

I'am a new  hand in OpenCV , thank you for your answers!

Comment: It seems you have never used the argument gotten from `get_mpl_colormap` method. I mean `cmap_name`. Is it redundant?

Comment: Here `roi_select_11 = rgb2hed(roi_select)` you convert RGB to HED, but the `roi_selected` is not RGB. In OpenCV the standard of channels are BGR.

Comment: @ElyasKarimi For your second question,yes ,you are right,but I can't fix it.

Comment: @ElyasKarimi For your first question,yes ,it's my falut,It is  redundant.

Comment: Why don't you convert them into BGR first? You can do that using `img_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(roi_select, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)`

Comment: @ElyasKarimi Yeah,RGB or BGR i can use `roi_select_11[:,:,0]` or `roi_select_11[:,:,2]`  get it ,but  I still can't get the figure2  .

Comment: have you considered the difference between `cv2.imshow` and `plt.imshow`? This link explains the difference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38598118/difference-between-plt-show-and-cv2-imshow

Answer (score 0):

For a quick fix, you can do

```
image_bgr = cv2.applyColorMap(255 - roi_select[:,:,0],get_mpl_colormap('bwr'))
cv2.imshow('image with colormap', image_bgr)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Using `255 - roi_select[:,:,0]` just look similar, but there are still some different from figure2.Thank you