# Unclear difference in displaying the same image by opencv and matplotlib

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, image-processing, colormap

During my work on image processing I encounter a strange phenomenon that is not clear to me.

I have an image with dimensions of: (256, 256, 1)
And when I display it with opencv using the following code:

```
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

I get the following result:

[image: image from opencv]

In contrast, when I display it with matplotlib using the following code:

```
plt.imshow(image, cmap="gray")
```

I get the following result:

[image: image output from matplotlib]

The second result is the desired one as far as I'm concerned -
my question is how to make the image like this (by code only and without the need to save to a file and load the image) and make it so that I get the same image in opencv as well.

I researched the issue but did not find a solution.

[This reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71518145/whats-the-difference-in-printing-an-image-to-the-screen-using-opencv-and-matplo) helps me understand the reason in general but I'm still don't know how to show the image in opencv like matplotlib view in this case.

Thank you!

Comment: matplotlib uses a color mapping. lookup the LUT for `cmap="gray"` and use that with `cv.applyColorMap` to achieve the same result

Comment: I've also tried that: ```cv2.applyColorMap(image, cv2.COLORMAP_JET)``` and get this error: ```cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\colormap.cpp:736: error: (-5:Bad argument) cv::ColorMap only supports source images of type CV_8UC1 or CV_8UC3 in function 'cv::colormap::ColorMap::operator ()'
```

Comment: has nothing to do with colormaps. has everything to do with value ranges and data types. explore the `image.max()` and `image.dtype`

Comment: Thank you! If there is an example a little more specific to my case it could help me better understand how to use them

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unclear difference in displaying the same image by opencv and matplotlib \[with example code & exported .npy file\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73350318/unclear-difference-in-displaying-the-same-image-by-opencv-and-matplotlib-with-e)

Comment: it's essentially the same question so there's no good reason to ask it twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I post the answer in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73350318/unclear-difference-in-displaying-the-same-image-by-opencv-and-matplotlib-with-e/73350813#73350813), Also copy to here:

```
   int_image = image.astype(np.uint8)

    cv2.imshow('image', int_image)
    cv2.waitKey()
    plt.imshow(image, cmap="gray")
    plt.title("image")
    plt.show()
```

Now - The 2 plots are same.

Hope this helps more people in the future