# Unclear difference in displaying the same image by opencv and matplotlib [with example code & exported .npy file]

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, matplotlib, image-processing

In continue to my previous question ([that still not answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73320666/unclear-difference-in-displaying-the-same-image-by-opencv-and-matplotlib))

Here is a simple code with some unsuccessful attempts and exported image.npy file that illustrates the problem:

```
'''
    conda install -c conda-forge opencv
    pip install numpy
    pip install matplotlib
'''

import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

if __name__ == "__main__":
    image = np.load('image.npy') # Link to the file under this code block

    print(image.shape) # output: (256, 256, 1)

    print(image.dtype) # output: float64

    # Unsuccessful attempts:
    # image[np.where(image.max() != 255)] = 0

    # max_img = image.max(axis=0)

    # int_image = image.astype(int)
```

[Link to download the image.npy file](https://f2h.io/mmvf24ol2jt7)

And when I display it with opencv using the following code:

```
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

I get an image like the following result:

[image: image from opencv]

In contrast, when I display it with matplotlib using the following code:

```
plt.imshow(image, cmap="gray")
```

(The 'cmap' parameter is not the issue here, It's only plot the image in Black & White)

I get an image the following result:

[image: image output from matplotlib]

The second result is the desired one as far as I'm concerned -
my question is how to make the image like this (by code only and without the need to save to a file and load the image) and make it so that I get the same image in opencv as well.

I researched the issue but did not find a solution.

[This reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71518145/whats-the-difference-in-printing-an-image-to-the-screen-using-opencv-and-matplo) helps me understand the reason in general but I'm still don't know how to show the image in opencv like matplotlib view in this case.

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unclear difference in displaying the same image by opencv and matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73320666/unclear-difference-in-displaying-the-same-image-by-opencv-and-matplotlib)

Comment: it's essentially the same question so there's no good reason to ask it twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following steps:

1. load the data from the file
2. truncate the data into 0-255 values, same type as original (float64)
3. filtering using the `==` operator, which gives True/False values, then multiplying by 255 to get 0/255 integer values
4. use `cv2.imshow` combined with `astype` to get the required type

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = np.load(r'image.npy')
    data2 = np.trunc(data)
    data3 = (data2 == 255) * 255
    cv2.imshow('title', data3.astype('float32'))
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 3):

Finally, I found the solution:

```
    int_image = image.astype(np.uint8)

    cv2.imshow('image', int_image)
    cv2.waitKey()
    plt.imshow(image, cmap="gray")
    plt.title("image")
    plt.show()
```

Now - The 2 plots are same.

Hope this helps more people in the future

Answer (score 1):

You have very few unique values in `image`, and their distribution is severely skewed. The next smallest value below 255 is 3.something, leaving a huge range of values unused.

- `image.max() == 255`
- `sorted(set(im.flat)) == [0.0, 0.249, 0.499, 0.748, 0.997, 1.246, 1.496, 1.745, 1.994, 2.244, 2.493, 2.742, 2.992, 3.241, 3.490, 3.739, 3.989, 255.0]`

`cv.imshow`, given floats, will map 0.0 to black and 1.0 to white. That is why your picture looks like

[image]

Your options:

- convert to `uint8` using `image.astype(np.uint8)` because `cv.imshow`, given `uint8` data, maps 0 to black and 255 to white
- divide by 255, so your values, being float, range from 0 to 1
- normalize by whatever way you want, but remember how `imshow` behaves given a certain element type and range of values. It also accepts `uint16`, but not `int` (which would be int32/int64).

[image: image.astype(np.uint8)]

The *other* answer, recommending `np.trunc` and stuff, is just messing around. The `trunc` doesn't change any of the `255.0` values (in the comparison), it's redundant. There's no need to threshold the data, unless you *need* such a result. It is also wrong in that it tells you to take a binary array, blow its value range up 0 to 255, and then convert to float, which is pointless, because `imshow`, given float, expects a value range of 0 to 1. Either the `*255` step is pointless, or the `astype` step should have used `uint8`.